# How to get maximum sequence number reset with a given condition in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the following data:
[image]

and i need to calculate the count of continuous sequence over the ConversationID and then reset the counter from the begging when the SequenceNumber = '1', so the output would be:
[image]

could anyone please help?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it with sql query, why not load required values  and calculate it by using any programming language you are using?

Comment: How it would be done, as you see i need to get the max per continues sequence..

Comment: Please remove images of the data and instead return original post, simpler for people to copy-paste

Comment: the rows of your data shown is based on what which column(s) for ordering ?

Comment: @Fabio, i noticed that when i past the original data it doesn't look well (hard to read).

Comment: @Squirrel, I ordered them based on the ConversationId

Comment: what about those with same `ConversationId` ?

Comment: If you can see that the same conversationID in the original data have multiple sequences (e.g. the first sequence is 1, the second one is 1,2 then 1,2,3,4,5 ...)

Comment: @YousefShamasneh . . . Please explain the logic used for calculating the `sequenceNumber`.

Comment: sequenceNumber depends on the difference between the messageDate and the PreviousMessageDate so if the difference > 10 minutes we start count from the beginning

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the last row of each sequence.  So, use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(sequencenumber) over (partition by conversationid order by messageid, sequencenumber) as next_sn
      from t
     ) t
where next_sn is null or
      next_sn <> sequencenumber + 1;
```

Comment: sorry but why did you ordered by messageid? i've tried your query and got something different ;(